# Symfony4: The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form

Tags: php, symfony

The following error occurred in Symfony4.
There are many posts with the same error, but I couldn't find the one in this case.
When I deleted the `//Error part` in the Twig file, the error disappeared, so I know it's the cause, but I don't know how to fix it.
What are your good ideas?

However, deleteAction is not used in `//Error part` and is incomprehensible.

```
The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form.
```

Article.php

```php
    protected function deleteAction(Request $request, $ids)
    {
        $token = $request->request->get('_csrf_token');
        $csrf_token = new CsrfToken('authenticate', $token);
        if (!$this->get("security.csrf.token_manager")->isTokenValid($csrf_token)) {
            //Error code
            throw new HttpException("400", "The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form.");
        }
    }
```

index.html.twig

```
    {{ form_start(form) }}
        <div class="formGroup trendTags"
            data-prototype="{{ macros.trendTagForm(form.trendTags.vars.prototype)|e }}"
            data-index="{{ ec_tag_contents|length }}">

            <label>Tag</label>
            <button type="button" class="add btn">Add</button>
            <ul class="trend-tag-list2" {% if not ec_tag_contents|default %} style="display:none"{% endif %} id="trendTagsWrap">
                {% for tag in ec_tag_contents|default %}
                    <li>
                        <div class="tagForm">
                            <div class="input-trendtag-display-name">&nbsp;{{ tag.name }}</div>
                            <div class="input-trendtag-display-term">({{ tag.str_tag_display }}  {{ tag.str_term }})</div>
                            <br>
                            {% for category in tag.categories|split(',') %}
                            <div class="tag-form__category-sticker" name="{{ category }}">{{ category }}</div>
                            {% endfor %}
                            <button class="removeTrendTag"><i class="icon-remove"></i></button>
                        </div>
                        <div id="brandevent_trendTags_{{ loop.index0 }}">
                            <input type="hidden" id="brandevent_trendTags_{{ loop.index0 }}_trendTagId" name="brandevent[trendTags][{{ loop.index0 }}][trendTagId]" required="required" value="{{ tag.tag_id }}">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                {% endfor %}
                {% do form.trendTags.setRendered(true) %}
            </ul>
        </div>
        {{ form_rest(form) }}
    {{ form_end(form) }}
    {% set url = path("app_hq_article_index", {"articleType": "article", "num": 5, "modal": true}) %}
    <div id="relatedArticleDialog" title="Article Selection" data-url="{{ url }}">
    </div>
    //Error part
     {% set q = app.request.query.get("q")|default({}) %}
     {% set trendTagUrl = path("app_hq_article_trendtag", {"q[sex]": q.sex|default(0), "q[brand_id]": q.brand_id|default(), "q[del_flg]": 0}) %}
     <div id="trendTagDialog" title="Tag Selection" data-url="{{ trendTagUrl }}">
     </div>
```

trendTag.html.twig

```
    <div class="search">
        {% include '@AppBundle/Shop/Article/trendTagForm.html.twig' %}
    </div>
```

trendTagForm.html.twig

```
<form id="frm-trend-tag-search" name="frm-trend-tag-search" method="get" action="{{path('app_hq_article_trendtag')}}">
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token('authenticate') }}">
...
</form>
```

Comment: the value of the token is "tag.tag_id" , you can pass the default token and concatenate it with tag.tag_id. and in the controller do the same thing

Comment: @hous Thanks for your comment. You just have to connect them.
Unfortunately I don't know how to connect. What should I do.
By the way, the token passed elsewhere is the code below.
```<input type =" hidden "name =" _ csrf_token "value =" {{csrf_token ('authenticate')}} ">```

Answer (score 2):

Add the `{{form_widget(form._token)}}` hidden field to the main form

or

Disable the CSRF token in form config:

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'csrf_protection' => false,
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, there was no improvement.

Comment: I put ```'csrf_protection' => false,``` in the Type that seems to be related to this error. I also tried putting ```{{form._token}}``` or ```{{form_row(form._token)}}```, ```{{form_widget(form._token)}}```, on top of ```{{form_rest (form)}}```, but I got the following error: ```Neither the property" _token "nor one of the methods" _token()","get_token()"/"is_token()"/" has_token()"or"__call()"exist and have public access in class "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView" .```

Comment: @scottie320 are you sure you are not setting the `'csrf_protection' => false` AND trying to use the `._token` silmutenously? If that's not the case, add `'csrf_field_name' => '_token'` in the form's `configureOptions` function

Comment: I tried it on the brandevent form and got similar results. By the way, if you delete ```// Error part```, the error displayed on the network of the chrome verification tool disappears, but for the brand event form, ```{{form_widget (form._token) Is it correct to include}} ```?